# Left shift key does not have the same behavior as right shift button

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

My left shift key does not work properly and I'm not sure why. When using the left shift key, I'm not able to capitalize the letter 'c' and I cannot do a `ctrl`+`shift_L`+`c`. However, this works fine when using the right shift button.

I have tried remapping the keys by switching both shift keys with each other. So Left acts as Right and Right acts as Left. However, the problem still persists. Here's the current setup I have but I will revert it back to default since it really doesn't help:

```
$ xmodmap -pke | grep Shift
keycode  50 = Shift_R NoSymbol Shift_R
keycode  62 = Shift_L NoSymbol Shift_L
keycode  92 = ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift
```

and this was the default config:

```
$ xmodmap -pke | grep Shift
keycode  50 = Shift_L NoSymbol Shift_L
keycode  62 = Shift_R NoSymbol Shift_R
keycode  92 = ISO_Level3_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level3_Shift
```

Here's the `xev` output using the remapping:

```
KeyPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x13f, subw 0x0, time 10906033, (383,267), root:(473,379),
    state 0x10, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe2, Shift_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x13f, subw 0x0, time 10909344, (383,267), root:(473,379),
    state 0x11, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe2, Shift_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x13f, subw 0x0, time 10914725, (383,267), root:(473,379),
    state 0x10, keycode 62 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x13f, subw 0x0, time 10916676, (383,267), root:(473,379),
    state 0x11, keycode 54 (keysym 0x43, C), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (43) "C"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x13f, subw 0x0, time 10916898, (383,267), root:(473,379),
    state 0x11, keycode 54 (keysym 0x43, C), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (43) "C"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x13f, subw 0x0, time 10916898, (383,267), root:(473,379),
    state 0x11, keycode 54 (keysym 0x43, C), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (43) "C"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x13f, subw 0x0, time 10916930, (383,267), root:(473,379),
    state 0x11, keycode 54 (keysym 0x43, C), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (43) "C"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x13f, subw 0x0, time 10916930, (383,267), root:(473,379),
    state 0x11, keycode 54 (keysym 0x43, C), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (43) "C"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x13f, subw 0x0, time 10916961, (383,267), root:(473,379),
    state 0x11, keycode 54 (keysym 0x43, C), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (43) "C"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x13f, subw 0x0, time 10916961, (383,267), root:(473,379),
    state 0x11, keycode 54 (keysym 0x43, C), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (43) "C"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x13f, subw 0x0, time 10916991, (383,267), root:(473,379),
    state 0x11, keycode 54 (keysym 0x43, C), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (43) "C"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x13f, subw 0x0, time 10916991, (383,267), root:(473,379),
    state 0x11, keycode 54 (keysym 0x43, C), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (43) "C"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x13f, subw 0x0, time 10917022, (383,267), root:(473,379),
    state 0x11, keycode 54 (keysym 0x43, C), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (43) "C"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x13f, subw 0x0, time 10917022, (383,267), root:(473,379),
    state 0x11, keycode 54 (keysym 0x43, C), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (43) "C"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x13f, subw 0x0, time 10917052, (383,267), root:(473,379),
    state 0x11, keycode 54 (keysym 0x43, C), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (43) "C"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x13f, subw 0x0, time 10917052, (383,267), root:(473,379),
    state 0x11, keycode 54 (keysym 0x43, C), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (43) "C"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x13f, subw 0x0, time 10917083, (383,267), root:(473,379),
    state 0x11, keycode 54 (keysym 0x43, C), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (43) "C"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x13f, subw 0x0, time 10917083, (383,267), root:(473,379),
    state 0x11, keycode 54 (keysym 0x43, C), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (43) "C"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x13f, subw 0x0, time 10917113, (383,267), root:(473,379),
    state 0x11, keycode 54 (keysym 0x43, C), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (43) "C"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x13f, subw 0x0, time 10917113, (383,267), root:(473,379),
    state 0x11, keycode 54 (keysym 0x43, C), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (43) "C"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x13f, subw 0x0, time 10917144, (383,267), root:(473,379),
    state 0x11, keycode 54 (keysym 0x43, C), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (43) "C"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x13f, subw 0x0, time 10917144, (383,267), root:(473,379),
    state 0x11, keycode 54 (keysym 0x43, C), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (43) "C"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x13f, subw 0x0, time 10917175, (383,267), root:(473,379),
    state 0x11, keycode 54 (keysym 0x43, C), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (43) "C"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x13f, subw 0x0, time 10917175, (383,267), root:(473,379),
    state 0x11, keycode 54 (keysym 0x43, C), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (43) "C"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x13f, subw 0x0, time 10917205, (383,267), root:(473,379),
    state 0x11, keycode 54 (keysym 0x43, C), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (43) "C"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x13f, subw 0x0, time 10917205, (383,267), root:(473,379),
    state 0x11, keycode 54 (keysym 0x43, C), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (43) "C"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x13f, subw 0x0, time 10917207, (383,267), root:(473,379),
    state 0x11, keycode 54 (keysym 0x43, C), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (43) "C"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 33, synthetic NO, window 0x3800001,
    root 0x13f, subw 0x0, time 10917788, (383,267), root:(473,379),
    state 0x11, keycode 62 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Notice how I can still capitalize using the right shift even though it is mapped as the left shift but I'm still unable to do so with the left shift acting as the right shift. I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, so everything is still in default. Keyboard layout is US and language is US as well. I checked if there are bindings to it but there's none. The left shift button is also in good physical condition. At this point, I'm not sure where to find the problem because the issue seems to be something else than being a broken key. Please advise.

One more question, if this is a gnome specific issue, will it still persist if I use a different wm like i3 and remove gnome entirely?

Comment: To your last paragraph, the answer is "no". So I encourage you to go ahead and try it in another WM or even in the virtual console. If it does not work, please add the output of `/etc/default/keyboard`.

Comment: @Quasímodo okay, thanks! I'll leave this post for now and will try to use a different WM. I still hope that this is just an issue that can be fixed within gnome and not having to transition into a different WM.

Comment: @Quasímodo I've switched to i3 but the issue still occurs.
`# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
`